# Não consigo centralizar o título

Tags: react, react-native, header, react-navigation

Usando react-native e react-navigation, por alguma razão nada que tentei funcionou para centralizar o título.

Tentativas:

1. AlignSelf

```
export default class First extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Start',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#000080',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 20,
            alignSelf: 'center',
        },
    }
```

2. TextAlign

```
export default class First extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Start',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#000080',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 20,
            textAlign: 'center',
        },
    }
```

3. Ambos

```
export default class First extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Start',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#000080',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 20,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            textAlign: 'center',
        },
    }
```

Tentei também utilizar headerRight/headerLeft vazios, mas nada aconteceu.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você não está definindo o display do cabeçalho. Para resolver esse problema basta adicionar `flex:1`. No caso, no seu código ficaria:

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Start',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000080',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        flex: 1,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
}
```

É possível ver o código funcionando com alinhamento a esquerda [nesse link](https://snack.expo.io/BJCyqEGPB)

Extraindo [da documentação](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#adjusting-header-styles):

> headerTitleStyle: if we want to customize the fontFamily, fontWeight and other Text style properties for the title, we can use this to do it.

Ou seja, em tradução livre, o `headerTitleStyle` utiliza as propriedades de [estilo do `Text`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props).

Answer (score -5):

Utiliza a propriedade `headerTitleAlign = 'center'`

Comment: Não publique código em links ou imagens. Código deve ser publicado como texto no corpo da resposta.